# How can I execute a python ML script on data queried with SQL within a Ruby on Rails app hosted on heroku + postgresql

Tags: python, sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku-postgres

I am using Heroku Dataclips, then I download the results of the query locally and I have written a script with python to run a machine learning model over it.

My question is, is there a way of loading the results of this query on the server, and running the python script over it, for later, recovering those results from a rails controller endpoint?

Comment: What is the actual question? Yes, python can connect to the database, it can store data anywhere, it can consume web services. But you need to put it all together, which is a complex task and cannot be answered here

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my question would be how can I store a python script in the heroku server to do so? I just write the script and put it somewhere within my app/ folder? With that script I could query the data and run the python code? and I could fetch it from a rails controller?

Comment: Controller is about user interaction with view, so I cannot imagine "fetching" something with it. What about storage: it needs some investigation, currently I cannot answer. But as Heroku is a platform for cloud apps, python code can at least be published as an application (for example, as a web service which produces model output in desired format and can be consumed for visualization with Rails).